SOLR Synonyms.txt path
enter image description here
I dont know why I cant run this schema and why it says that it can't find the my_synonyms.txt. When I use synonyms.txt it works even though I don't have any file named synonyms.txt. I am using docker and inside my docker there is a folder "data" and another "solrdata" where the my_synonyms.txt is. But i tried lots of combinations (/data/my_synonyms.txt, /data/solrdata/my_synonyms.txt and still doesnt work)

So what's under the path mentioned in the error message? /var/solr/data/priProj - also, please include error messages as text and not images; images aren't really searchable, is bad for assistive technologies and can't be copy-pasted.
